# Random DNA mutation Generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics

I'd like to create a dictionary of dictionaries for a series of mutated DNA strands, with each dictionary demonstrating the original base as well as the base it has mutated to.

To elaborate, what I would like to do is create a generator that allows one to input a specific DNA strand and have it crank out 100 randomly generated strands that have a mutation frequency of 0.66% (this applies to each base, and each base can mutate to any other base). Then, what I would like to do is create a series of dictionary, where each dictionary details the mutations that occured in a specific randomly generated strand. I'd like the keys to be the original base, and the values to be the new mutated base. Is there a straightforward way of doing this? So far, I've been experimenting with a loop that looks like this:

```
#yields a strand with an A-T mutation frequency of 0.066%
def mutate(string, mutation, threshold):
    dna = list(string)
    for index, char in enumerate(dna):
        if char in mutation:
            if random.random() < threshold:
                dna[index] = mutation[char]

    return ''.join(dna)

dna = "ATGTCGTACGTTTGACGTAGAG"
print("DNA first:", dna)
newDNA = mutate(dna, {"A": "T"}, 0.0066)
print("DNA now:", newDNA)
```

But I can only yield one strand with this code, and it only focuses on T-->A mutations. I'm also not sure how to tie the dictionary into this. could someone show me a better way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you want the dictionary to contain? It seems like you could just keep a list of the indexes where the mutations happened, but it seems like you want more.

Comment: I want the dictionary to have the key being the original base, and the value being the mutated base. For instance, If I had an original strand looking like this: "ATGT", and the mutated strand looking like this: "AGTT", I want the dictionary of this strand to look like this: {T:G,G:T}

Comment: I'm not sure that can handle all situations though. You might mutate the same base multiple times (to different new values). How should that be handled? It would be easy enough to provide a list of `from,to` tuples, rather than a dictionary, I suppose.

Comment: how would the from,to tuples look? Just curious

Comment: Well, for the example in your comment, you'd give a list of tuples like `[("T", "G"), ("G", "T")]`. If you mutated `"ATGT"` to `"AGTC"` (adding an extra T->C mutation), you'd get `[("T", "G"), ("G", "T"), ("T", "C")]`. A dictionary couldn't (easily) do this, as its keys need to be unique. Now, you could also make your dictionaries keep a list of mutation results (e.g. `{"T":["G", "C"],"G":["T"]}`), but that's a bit cumbersome. You really need to think about how you're going to use the mutation data, and design your data structures to make that use easy.

Comment: The problem is I'm not sure how to make a generator that yields 100 lines rather than only one. I have some difficulties with the formatting.. I'm kinda new to this stuff

Comment: cross posted : https://www.biostars.org/p/102548

Comment: @user3670902 why not call it 100 times in a `for` loop, rather than try to have it `return` (it's not a generator, it doesn't `yield`) 100 values?

Comment: how would I call it 100 times?

Comment: @user3670902 At the risk of repeating myself, [in a `for` loop](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like there are two parts to your issue. The first is that you want to mutate your DNA sequence several times, and the second is that you want to gather some additional information about the mutations in a data structure of some kind. I'll handle each of those separately.

Producing 100 random results from the same source string is pretty easy. You can do it with an explicit loop (for instance, in a generator function), but you can just as easily use a list comprehension to run a single-mutation function over and over:

```
results = [mutate(original_string) for _ in range(100)]
```

Of course, if you make the `mutate` function more complicated, this simple code may not be appropriate. If it returns some kind of more sophisticated data structure, rather than just a string, you may need to do some additional processing to combine the data in the format you want.

As for how to build those data structures, I think the code you have already is a good start. You'll need to decide how exactly you're going to be accessing your data, and then let that guide you to the right kind of container.

For instance, if you just want to have a simple record of all the mutations that happen to a string, I'd suggest a basic list that contains tuples of the base before and after the mutation. On the other hand, if you want to be able to efficiently look up what a given base mutates to, a dictionary with lists as values might be more appropriate. You could also include the index of the mutated base if you wanted to.

Here's a quick attempt at a function that returns the mutated string along with a list of tuples recording all the mutations:

```
bases = "ACGT"

def mutate(orig_string, mutation_rate=0.0066):
    result = []
    mutations = []
    for base in orig_string:
        if random.random() < mutation_rate:
            new_base = bases[bases.index(base) - random.randint(1, 3)] # negatives are OK
            result.append(new_base)
            mutations.append((base, new_base))
        else:
            result.append(base)
    return "".join(result), mutations
```

The most tricky bit of this code is how I'm picking the replacement of the current base. The expression `bases[bases.index(base) - random.randint(1, 3)]` does it all in one go. Lets break down the different bits. `bases.index(base)` gives the index of the previous base in the global `bases` string at the top of the code. Then I subtract a random offset from this index (`random.randint(1, 3)`). The new index may be negative, but that's OK, as when we use it to index back into the `bases` string (`bases[...]`), negative indexes count from the right, rather than the left.

Here's how you could use it:

```
string = "ATGT"
results = [mutate(string) for _ in range(100)]
for result_string, mutations in results:
    if mutations: # skip writing out unmutated strings
        print(result_string, mutations)
```

For short strings, like `"ATGT"` you're very unlikely to get more than one mutation, and even one is pretty rare. The loop above tends to print between 2 and 4 results on each run (that is, more than 95% of length-four strings are not mutated at all). Longer strings will have mutations more often, and it's more plausible that you'll see multiple mutations in one string.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, I seem to be getting an error once I started testing the code - I think it's a problem on my end. I made some tweaks to the code you showed above (I inputted the string I wanted to use), and I've shown that in my EDIT. Have any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: @user3670902 I have rolled back your edit; you should not significantly change the question. The code you posted was very confused, and had indentation issues - you shouldn't have "loose" code in a `class` definition - it should be inside method `def`initions.

Comment: I'm sorry jonrsharpe, but where am I supposed to post my edit? I wasn't aware of the indentation issues, which is why I posted it. How am I supposed to properly post my edit, then?

Comment: @user3670902 Don't just do the same thing again! If you have a new issue, that should be a new question. First, you should read through [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) on classes. If you do need to ask, try to reduce your code to a [minimal working example](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem, don't just dump the whole code in.

Comment: Blckknght, would it be okay if you could explain the code you posted there? I would like to understand the reasoning behind what you did, especially these lines: if random.random() < mutation_rate:
                new_base = bases[bases.index(base) - random.randint(1, 3)]

Comment: @user3670902: I've added a paragraph explaining that bit of code, which picks the new base when a mutation occurs.

Comment: I've been having problems with the print statement when I try to place the function under a class. maybe you could help? I've posted it as a different question, though. Let me know if I could forward that to you.